# WebForm_SaveScrollPositionSubmit is undefined - ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, javascript, .net-2.0, maintainscrollpositionon

I'm upgrading an ASP.NET 1.1 app and have things working but am seeing the Javascript error referenced in the title.  From research it appears that ASP.NET is not spitting out the javascript that is used to maintain scroll position between postbacks.

I did some googling and have checked the various issues mentioned but can't seem to find what might be going on.

Environment details:

- IIS 6 on Win Server 2003
- The virtual directory is running ASP.NET 2.0.50727
- I have set maintainScrollPositionOnPostBack="True" in the  section of web.config

Any ideas?

Comment: What happens when you set MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback to true in @Page directive? Does this work?

Answer (score 2):

Do you have any httphandlers or httpmodules that do any kind of request filtering or re-writing ? or anything special in global.asax that would prevent the javascript from coming down ? I would guess that something is blocking the built in axd request to get the javascript that deals with WebForm_SaveScrollPositionSubmit.

To find out for sure fire up [Fiddler](http://www.fiddlertool.com/fiddler/) and watch the HTTP requests and make sure they are all happening correctly.

Also make sure there is at least 1 and only 1 form on the page.

Comment: Thank you - deleting the following line from .htaccess (using Helicon Ape) solved it for me - `mod_gzip_item_include mime application/x-javascript`. (By using Fiddler I could also see that the WebResource.axd downloaded size was 0 bytes)

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem to be timing issue. If the server has an older date/time to the built DLL, I was hitting this issue.